# Split Large Class With Method Chaining Into Smaller Class

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I have a OOP question about how to potentially separate a large class into smaller classes.

The class below has many methods. I have organised these methods into groups. Each group of public methods is applicable only to a specific sub-section of the real world business object that the class is representing. Ideally, I'd prefer to split this class into smaller classes, for example *(these are crude names but they are for illustrative purposes)*:

- MyBusinessObjectGroupOne
- MyBusinessObjectGroupTwo
- MyBusinessObjectGroupThree

Note that the public methods return the same class object because these methods are called using method chaining. Also, each group can and will have many more methods than just four.

```
public class MyBusinessObject{

    private object memberOne;
    private object memberTwo;
    private object memberThree;

    //METHOD GROUP ONE
    public MyBusinessObject Method1(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method2(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method3(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method4(){ }

    //METHOD GROUP TWO
    public MyBusinessObject Method5(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method6(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method7(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method8(){ }

    //METHOD GROUP THREE
    public MyBusinessObject Method9(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method10(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method11(){ }
    public MyBusinessObject Method12(){ }

    //METHOD GROUP FOUR
    private void Method13(){ }
    private void Method14(){ }
    private void Method15(){ }
    private void Method16(){ }
}
```

There are three aspects of this class that are causing me difficulty with figuring out if this class can be split:

1. The aforementioned method chaining
2. Although methods in each public group don't call methods in other public groups, the methods in the private group can be called by any public method in any group.
3. Likewise, the class members are accessed and modified by methods in all four groups.

Therefore, I am unsure if it is possible to split this class into separate classes for some or all of these reasons.

I have considered moving the methods in the private group to a new class (e.g. `MyUtils`); and also moving the class members to another new class (e.g. `MyData`) whose instance could be passed to `MyUtils` by `ref`.

Therefore, I could move each of the method groups into their own class, pass in `MyData` by `ref`, and they could each use `MyUtils` too.

Is this the right approach for points 2 and 3 above?
I'm unsure about the implications to the method chaining of moving those methods to new classes.

**EDIT**
This is a response to a pertinent comment below. I'm looking into this to simply reduce the size of the class. I'm not aiming to add any additional architectural flexibility or functionality by splitting the class. It is basically for code structure and organisation. I'm also aware that code in a large class with methods in distinct separate logical groups may violate the single responsibility principle.

Comment: It sounds like you could have one abstract base class with three implementations (one for each "group"). The base could then have all of the shared members as well as four abstract methods that the derived classes would implement

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it to reduce the size of the (perhaps massive) source file that implements `MyBusinessObject`? If so, using the `partial` modifier on a set of separate files, all of which combine to implement your one big class. Splitting things up means figuring out how to manage the state the class maintains and providing a way to call a method in one of the other class implementations. Abstract base classes, interfaces, etc. are just complications that will come back to bite you while you maintain this.

Comment: @Flydog57 That is a good question. Yes, it is to reduce the size of the class. I'm not aiming to add any additional architectural flexibility or functionality by splitting the class. It is basically for code structure and organisation. I'm also aware that code a in large class with methods in distinct separate logical groups may violate the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @JohnSteed it sounds like you've figured out that all methods are related to a single reason for the class to change. It's probably not so common, but I guess it's possible. In that case, the partial class solution is probably the best one, if you don't like a single file with tons of code. In the end, it's one class. I would probably reconsider the fact that they could be different classes, though.

Comment: Add partial like in a windows form project so you can have one class in more than one module : public partial class Form1 : Form

Comment: Is there a requirement to be able to chain methods between various public groups? Meaining, is there ever a situation like this: `myObj.Method1().Method8();` where `Method1` and `Method8` are in different public groups?

Comment: Wow. What a mess. I feel there are big design issues that are causing this in the first place. There shouldnt be so many direct dependencies between all of the methods.
Ideally you would need to redesign this to have several sets of Business classes, each of them responsible for its own part, dependant on each other through abstractions. 
However since it would be too much work to redesign this from scratch I dont think there is much that can be done here now. Just keep things organised and you will be fine (until a certain point)

Comment: Use the compiler's partial class capability. A class can be composed of many different source files if you declare the class in each file using the `partial` keyword. The compiler simply gathers the class fragments in each file and glues them into a single class. You can name each file in a way that makes clear the purpose of each class fragment. You get the benefit of cleanly cleaving your class into chunks, while still having a single class

Comment: @CoolBots, yes there is. Internally, `Method1` would never call `Method8` but it is a perfectly valid scenario for the caller to use `myObj.Method1().Method8();`

Comment: @Tanuki, the requirement for method chaining seems to be the main reason that is preventing me from separating this into multiple classes. This is a requirement that is imposed upon me, I must fulfill it. Any changes I make can only be internal and cannot affect how the class is declared or how the methods are called.

Answer (score -1):

You can make `MyBusinessObject` a base class, remove from there the groups-specific methods, only leave there the methods that are shared by all groups with `protected` access modifier. Then create three classes that derive from `MyBusinessObject` so that all three have access to the shared methods. Then on each of those classes include the group-specific methods. That should give you smaller classes with the capability to do chaining. Something like this:

```cs
public class MyBusinessObject {

    // You might need to move these to one of the derived classes .......
    private object memberOne;
    private object memberTwo;
    private object memberThree;

    //METHOD GROUP FOUR
    protected void Method13(){ }
    protected void Method14(){ }
    protected void Method15(){ }
    protected void Method16(){ }
}

public class Group1 : MyBusinessObject 
{
    //METHOD GROUP ONE
    public Group1 Method1(){ }
    public Group1 Method2(){ }
    public Group1 Method3(){ }
    public Group1 Method4(){ }
}

public class Group2 : MyBusinessObject 
{
    //METHOD GROUP TWO
    public Group2 Method5(){ }
    public Group2 Method6(){ }
    public Group2 Method7(){ }
    public Group2 Method8(){ }
}

public class Group3 : MyBusinessObject 
{
    //METHOD GROUP THREE
    public Group3 Method9(){ }
    public Group3 Method10(){ }
    public Group3 Method11(){ }
    public Group3 Method12(){ }
}
```

EDIT:

Based on clarification, this approach will not work since it might be needed to chain calls across different groups.

Based on this information, the easiest thing to do IMHO to make code more readable is to split it in different files using `partial` classes. Probably the right thing to do would be to revisit the design and create smaller, more concise and narrow classes, but this would involve a refactoring effort which could be expensive.

Comment: So... why is this better in OP's case than using the `partial` keyword, that's practically designed for this purpose?

Comment: Actually, this method doesn't work at all for OP's case - you can't chain the calls between groups. How would you call `Group1.Method3()` on an object returned by `Group2.Method5()`?

Comment: This is inheritance abuse in every way you look at it.

Comment: In response to @CoolBots, the question tells "Each group of public methods is applicable only to a specific sub-section of the real world business object that the class is representing". This seems to imply that methods in different groups do not need to be chained. Also, to address your other comment about the OP case, using the `partial` keyword will give you smaller files, but all members will belong to the same class. If the class represents multiple "real world business subsections", it might be better creating it different classes instead of a god class.

Comment: So, let's clarify with OP: @JohnSteed, is there a need to be able to chain methods between public groups? *EDIT*: I asked on the main question. My understanding was, from reading the post, that there is such a need. Let's see - if the OP says there is not, then you're right, and I'll remove my downvote; otherwise, your answer simply doesn't work, and you should probably remove it.

Comment: Thank you CoolBots. I understood the question differently, probably it is a bit broad to give a good answer. Probably for the same reason it is not accurate to tell it is inheritance abuse (in response to @Flater comment) without knowing the real intent of that class and methods.

Comment: @IvanVargas no worries! Per OP's response: *yes there is. Internally, `Method1` would never call `Method8` but it is a perfectly valid scenario for the caller to use `myObj.Method1().Method8();`* - this issue is now clarified. Unfortunately, this renders your solution, as currently written, impractical.

Comment: @IvanVargas awesome, thanks! I removed my downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing it via extensions (pseudocode)

```cs
static class ExtensionGroup1
{
    public static MyBusinessObject Method1_1(){ this MyBusinessObject onj, ... }
    public static  MyBusinessObject Method1_2(){  this MyBusinessObject onj, ...  }
    public static MyBusinessObject Method1_3(){  this MyBusinessObject onj, ...  }
    public static MyBusinessObject Method1_4(){  this MyBusinessObject onj, ...  }
}


static class ExtensionGroup2
{
    public static MyBusinessObject Method2_1(){ this MyBusinessObject onj, ... }
    . . . .  .. 
}
```

Then in your main class, you can do...

```cs
class Context
{
     int Var1 {get;set}
     int Var2 {get;set}
}

private int _var1;
private bool _var2; 

void SomeMethod(MyBusinessObject someObject)
{
    var ctx = new Context(){ Var1 = _var1, Var2 = _var2 }

    this.Method1_1(ctx).Method2_1(ctx)...

}
```

Note this - You will be able to mix methods for same or different groups. And, especially note that your extensions will need to use your currently main class as a context class, hence `Method1_1(this)`

Comment: One issue with this approach is that there are private members of `MyBusinessObject` that need to be accessed in `MethodX`, those private members would need to be exposed outside of `MyBusinessObject`

Comment: @T.S.Properties are syntax sugar, they get compiled to methods, i.e. for property `int A { get; set;}` the compiler generates methods get_A and set_A. If a property is declared `public int A { get; private set; }`one can see the property outside its class, but one cannot set it. Anyways, the question has private fields and methods and mentions those private methods need to be accessed in the public methods, which it not possible  doing the approach you proposed *unless* those private methods are changed to `internal` or `public`.

Comment: @IvanVargas See my previous comment. Nevertheless. I still see this approach as possible solution. As you see in the call chain, I nave `.Method2_1(this)`. You're talking of refactoring effort here anyways. So, where you see `this`, I've mentioned a "context class". So. Inside your `MyBusinessObject`, you would create a class `Context`, which will be a carrier of your private field data through method execution, like, `this.Method2_1(context).Method4_1(context)`. This is what I really mean.